# Why does text quality improve at certain sizes?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have noticed that with almost every font I use on the web (and I'm mainly using webfonts from Google) that at certain sizes fonts tend to look a lot better.

I've always been told it's a good idea to stick to the typographic scale whenever possible. The problem is, when I do, my text in the browser always looks worse (more jagged, as if it has no anti-aliasing).

For example, I am using the font maven_probold (although this issue applies to many, if not all, of the fonts I use in one way or another). When I set the size to 3em (48px) the font appears very jagged and not very pleasing. However, if I bump it up to 3.5em it appears extremely smooth.

Is this a phenomenon that everyone experiences? Has anyone ever understood why this happens? I'm using Google Chrome to design in.

EDIT: Here is what I'm talking about. Pay attention to the curves, specifically the O and the Rs.

http://gyazo.com/3d238487b45f5bd68cdfab0b3aae871a.png
http://gyazo.com/86a8564aaf2ff370da1a537dd3804eb3.png

Comment: In my personal experience, Chrome on Windows is one of the worst browsers at font rendering, and especially with Google Web Fonts for some reason :(

Answer (score 0):

Chrome on Windows has quite well documented problems with font rendering.

My suggestion is to try on FireFox, IE and a Mac if possible. It looks a bit ugly but I am yet to find a good solution using CSS that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Going purely by your example images, I can explain the "what" part: I see that in the smaller size, sub-pixel rendering is in use. This is evident by the orange/brown color fringe on the left edge (and blue fringe on the right) which is a telltale sign of sub-pixel rendering (on Microsoft platforms, [ClearType](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/ClearTypeInfo.mspx), but there are other implementations on other platforms). In the larger image, whole-pixel antialiasing (commonly known as "greyscale") is in use, and in this example, happens to look "better".

As to *why*: that's harder to answer. There is a font table, known as the ['gasp' table](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/gasp.htm), that can be used to control when different rendering techniques should be used. This is set by the font maker. This table can be used by font renderers as an aid in switching rendering techniques. But, it's not always present in every font, and even if it is, some rendering systems may choose to ignore it (for example, Mac OS does not make use of this table at all).

If you can find a font tool that is capable of parsing/editing the 'gasp' table, you could examine the font and see if it has a 'gasp' table with values coinciding with your sizes. If so, you could possibly edit the font data and serve up the edited data instead.